# Appending ..mobile to end of view name behaving erratically

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to create a view that loads only for mobile sites.  [Apparently](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/aspnet-mvc-4-mobile-features), adding .mobile to a view name so _Layout.cshtml becomes _Layout.Mobile.cshtml causes that view to be loaded if the device is viewed on a mobile.  I have got this working for the very first view my VS project uses - _Layout.cshtml, but then in that file it loads `@Html.Partial(MVC.Shared.Views._Header, Model)`, I would have expected the same thing to happen with this, that it would know to load the _Header.Mobile.cshtml view instead, but it doesn't.  Does this mean I have to manually change all the references to views to have .Mobile at the end of them in the views?  I thought the point of the .Mobile was that it knew automatically to use this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say that you would have to load the partial by name for it to work, you are specifying a particular file there.

you could load it using

```
@Html.Partial("_Header", Model)
```

Comment: that's what I am doing, expecting it to pick up the _Header.Mobile view but it's only picking up the _Header file

Comment: have you tried exactly @Html.Partial("_Header", Model) instead of using the full MVC.Shared.Views._Header in your question

Comment: I'm also assuming this is _Header.Mobile.cshtml and _Header.cshtml that you have.

Comment: that works, thank you.  We use the razor engine to be able to choose the file, so maybe this razor engine doesn't work with the new .mobile functionality.

Comment: don't suppose you know the answer to this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13342894/the-function-renderbody-not-using-the-mobile-cshtml-view

Comment: @Nicola put an updated answer to your other question, comment on that question if I missed the point.  upvotes to answers always welcome as well ;)